Explanation of code sequence in "Murach's Python for Data Science"
The book is an excellent introduction to pandas, but occasionally leaves me hanging. Briefly, shots is a dataFrame containing info on Stephen Curry's shots during a full NBA season. action_type is a column in the dataFrame. The code below is from the book and is part of a solution to an exercise:
# Steps:
# pick common substring
# add actions that the substring covers to list
# query the shots for the actions until empty

commonSubstrings = ['Jump','Layup','Dunk','Fadeaway','Hook','Bank','Tip']
actions = shots[shots.action_type.str.contains('|'.join(commonSubstrings))].action_type.to_list()
shots.query('action_type not in @actions').action_type

# replace each shot type with the new label
def get_label(row):
     for s in commonSubstrings:
         if s in row.action_type:
             return s

shots['shot_type'] = shots.apply(lambda x: get_label(x), axis=1)

My question boils down to the second line of code:
actions = shots[shots.action_type.str.contains('|'.join(commonSubstrings))].action_type.to_list()

I need someone to fully explain all that is going on here.

What part (or parts) of that line do you not understand? Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271468/explain-x-to-me-questions-how-to-react and ensure that you provide enough explanation as indicated by the answers there. (I do not know Pandas so cannot answer the question. It may be that you can improve the question by explaining what you do and do not understand.)

Hi, welcome to SO! Did you check the relevant docs? E.g., Series.str.contains gives an example with alternative matches just like this solution.

This allows to search if any of the words in "commonSubstrings" is a substring of the strings in the "action_type" column, select the strings from the column and convert the resulting Series to python list.
First, this joins all words in a single string to form a regex. The | characters means OR in a regex:
'|'.join(commonSubstrings)
# 'Jump|Layup|Dunk|Fadeaway|Hook|Bank|Tip'

Note that the better practice would be to first escape each word in case it could contain a special character. (In this particular case, this is not an issue since only letters are used):
import re

'|'.join(map(re.escape, commonSubstrings))

Then str.contains with return a Series of True/False flagging each row that contains any of the words as True:
shots.action_type.str.contains('|'.join(commonSubstrings))

This Series is used for boolean indexing to select the rows that have a match and convert the Series to_list. Note that the better practice here would be to avoid selecting columns as attributes and to use loc:
shots.loc[shots['action_type'].str.contains('|'.join(map(re.escape, commonSubstrings))), 'action_type'].to_list()

Example:
shots = pd.DataFrame({'action_type': ['Sleep', 'Jump', 'Tiptoe']})
#   action_type
# 0       Sleep
# 1        Jump
# 2      Tiptoe

shots.action_type.str.contains('|'.join(commonSubstrings))
# 0    False
# 1     True
# 2     True
# Name: action_type, dtype: bool

shots.loc[shots['action_type'].str.contains('|'.join(map(re.escape, commonSubstrings))), 'action_type']
# 1      Jump
# 2    Tiptoe
# Name: action_type, dtype: object

shots.loc[shots['action_type'].str.contains('|'.join(map(re.escape, commonSubstrings))), 'action_type'].to_list()
# ['Jump', 'Tiptoe']

pure python variant:
out = [string for string in shots['action_type']
       if any(word in string for word in commonSubstrings)]

